# How can I do a callback after useState with a pure function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedSampleJobIndex !== undefined) {
      setAppState((s) => ({
        ...s,
        resumeInput: sampleJobValues[selectedSampleJobIndex],
      }));
    }
  }, [selectedSampleJobIndex]);
```

I want to do something once that appState is done. But it won't accept a second callback function.

How can I best handle this?

I can't easily use `useEffect`, because what's being changed is in a top level context and might also change due to user input

Comment: Why keep state in two locations? The context and this component? Or does context mean execution context rather than React Context Provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by calling your callback function in the updater function, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (selectedSampleJobIndex !== undefined) {
     setAppState((s) => {
       cb(); // Call your callback function here. You can pass it previous or next state
       return {...s, resumeInput: sampleJobValues[selectedSampleJobIndex]};
     });
   }
}, [selectedSampleJobIndex]);
```

This is the closest hooks equivalent to the `setState` callback parameter that can only be used in class components.

Note that the updater function should be a *pure function*, therefore be mindful of the effects of your callback. In principle, there should not be a need to invoke a callback after setting state with hooks. You can trigger an effect when the state changes by using the `useEffect` hook and including the state in the dependency array.

Comment: Can this be an `async` function?

Comment: I was in the middle of typing the same thing - this is the closest you'll get. +1

Comment: @Shamoon It can be, but it will delay the setting of the state. If this is a problem, you need a different implementation.

Comment: keep in mind the updater function which you pass to `setAppState` should be *pure*

Comment: @Shamoon this is an anti-pattern. Do not do this. You should share the code that depends on the updating state so the community can advise you appropriately.

Comment: @Mulan Yes I said that in my answer....